# scipy.io.wavfile.read cannot read 24-bits .wav files

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav

It seems that `scipy.io.wavfile.read` cannot read 24-bits .wav files.
Do you have an idea on how to handle them ?

Comment: It reads them into 32bit ints, what it cannot do is write them back as 24bit.

Comment: Jaime, no it doesnt read. when I try to used `read` for a 24-bits file, I get errors (`Traceback ...` `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`)

Comment: It does read single channel 24bit wavs, yours must be stereo. There's about half a dozen questions identical to yours in stackoverflow, you may want to use the search box...

Comment: As you can imagine, I've searched lots of identical questions... Either the method is complexe with some audiolab, etc., or it doesn't work...

But `scipy.io.wavfile.read` should read stereo 24-bits file. How can we modify this file in order to support such a common format ?

Comment: @Jaime: I get an error when reading a 24 bit wav file with a single channel and 9 frames (created using the `wave` module).  If instead there are 8 frames (so the number of bytes is a multiple of 4), `scipy.wavfile.read` reads the file, but the data ends up in an array of type int32 with length 6. The first value in the array holds the three bytes from first sample and one byte of the second sample, etc.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser There's some sick behavior from numpy involved, where the dtype is set to `'i3'` and it returns an `int32`, instead of raising an error. Sometimes the planets align and it gives you the data mangled, sometimes it fails miserably. It doesn't look like it would be too hard to read everything into `int8`s, do some reshaping magic, and convert into the next largest int type, but it would require returning the number of bits of the data, which couldn't be inferred from the dtype anymore. The only easy fix not requiring rethinking the user interface would be to raise an error...

Comment: @Jaime: OK, I was just pointing out that, while in some cases it might not raise an error, it doesn't really "work" in any useful way.  Your first comment seemed to imply that it might work and just upcast to 32 bits, and that was surprising, since I know you've looked into this and commented about the behavior in other questions.   P.S. I've just created a function that *can* read uncompressed wav files using the `wave` module.  I'll add it as a gist to the scipy issue about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an updated version of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds many things:

- 24 bit .wav files support for read/write,
- access to cue markers,
- cue marker labels,
- some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.

[wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)

Feel free to share it!

Comment: Usage wise there is an extra parameter (bits) compared to wavfile.read in Scipy.io  `Fs, data, bits = wavfile.read('input.wav')`

Answer (score 14):

If your wav files are not compressed, you can try the `readwav` function here: https://gist.github.com/WarrenWeckesser/7461781

---

**Update**

I converted that gist to a python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio

The source code is on github: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio

Comment: wonderful ! it works ! 
would you have a `writewav` also ? ;)

Comment: +1 But you probably want to return the bitdepth of the file together with the rate and data, as right now there's no way of telling whether you read a 32 or 24 bit file. Just to make things horrible, [apparently PCM supports 4, 12 and 20 bit depths](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=PCM#PCM_Parameters)...

Comment: @JosBas: I updated the gist.  It has a new file name (`wavio.py`) and a function `writewav24` for writing 24 bit wav files.  Again, not *thoroughly* tested, so caveat emptor.

Comment: @Jaime: Good idea.  I updated the gist; `readwav` now returns `rate, sampwidth, array`.

Comment: thanks Jaime and Warren for your ideas and your gist, wonderful !

Last thing (not 100% related with main topic but... ) : I also would like to read/write Markers metadatas included in the .wav, do you know how I can do this ?

Comment: @JosBas: Sorry, that's a bit beyond the scope of the simple functions in the gist.  It's just a wrapper around the functions from the python `wave` module, which ignores metadata.  I don't know if any of the "real" audio libraries (audiolab, pysox, others?) handle metadata, so all I can suggest is the google.

Answer (score 1):

scipy.io.wavfile.read can read 24-bits .wav files since release 1.6 :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.6.0/reference/release.1.6.0.html#scipy-io-improvements