# Unexpected end of file wavfile.read python

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, wav

I am trying to read .wav audio file by following code

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
file = 'PC1_20090513_050000_0010.wav'
rate, audio = wavfile.read(file)
```

but it is showing following error :

```
raise ValueError("Unexpected end of file.")
ValueError: Unexpected end of file.
```

Any idea ??

Comment: tried already with many sample files provided as training data

Comment: yes with non existing file results are different. It worked

Comment: file play ok in vlc bt cannot able to read it with wavfile.read

Comment: Do you know the format of the data in the wav file (e.g. bit depth, data type, etc)?  Also, which version of scipy are you using? You can check with `import scipy; print scipy.__version__`.

Comment: check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963180/scipy-io-wavfile-read-cannot-read-24-bits-wav-files

Comment: try to download old .wav files from the internet. Maybe your .wav files contain some unknown stuff and it fails.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you got incorrect data in the head of wav file (http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/). VLC sometimes can handle that.
Try to resave this file with any soft. For example use sox (http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and resample to the same frequency that were (like this: `sox.exe wav_file -r frequency out_wav_file`)