# scipy.io.wavfile.read cannot read 16-bits .wav files

Tags: python, scipy, wave

I have a problem with reading a wav file with 2bytes. I saw [scipy.io.wavfile.read cannot read 24-bits .wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963180/scipy-io-wavfile-read-cannot-read-24-bits-wav-files)

 and [Unexpected end of file wavfile.read python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419836/unexpected-end-of-file-wavfile-read-python)
 . but both of them relate to reading 24-bits file which `wavfile.read` cannot support it. Here is my code when i get information from my file

[image: sample width]

and here is when i want to read it but i have an error unexpected file.

[image: cannot read 16-bits]

EDIT: here is My sample .wav file
[Uploaded File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43243917206152088810)

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with the wav file you're trying to read. Have you tried loading some other wav file? If the problem persists you may want to upload a sample file so we can reproduce the problem. I also think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551663) may help you.

Comment: post edited and i uploaded a sample file

Comment: See my answer here, where I suggest trying [wavio](https://pypi.org/project/wavio/): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667042/how-to-fix-incomplete-wav-chunk-error-when-reading-wav-with-scipy/56670312#56670312.  `wavio.read` is able to read that file.

Comment: thnq you for replying, i used this library and successfully read it but there was a problem with ram when huge amount of data are read. i just want test another library to see the result

Comment: Actually i want to down sample my data but libraries like `librosa` is time consuming. if i can found a way to resample data before reading them to train with CNN, i can use `wavio` library to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Could reproduce your error. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551663), I "resampled" the file by running `sox 50.wav -r 44100 resampled_50.wav`.

Here the result:

```py
>>> from scipy.io import wavfile
>>> wavfile.read("50.wav")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 246, in read
    raise ValueError("Unexpected end of file.")
ValueError: Unexpected end of file.
>>> wavfile.read("resampled_50.wav")
(44100, array([[-2171, -2025],
       [-1306,  -510],
       [ -550,   591],
       ..., 
       [ -157,  -155],
       [ -166,  -170],
       [ -164,  -164]], dtype=int16))
>>>
```

Looks like this approach works. Hope it helps you!